# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of my current location using geolocation. Extremely similar code was working until recently, and I can't figure out why it stopped working. It is no longer setting the variables *latitude* or *longitude*. When I walk through the js code, the getCurrentPosition() method is skipped and I'm not sure why. Bizarrely, if I put an alert box in the getCurrentPosition() method, it will get and display the latitude and longitude correctly... I have no idea why it does that.

```
var gl;
try {
    if (typeof navigator.geolocation === 'undefined'){
        gl = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
    } else {
        gl = navigator.geolocation;
    }
} catch(e) {}

var latitude;
var longitude;

if (gl) {
    gl.getCurrentPosition(
        function (position) {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            //alert("got the lat & long - lat=" + latitude + ", lng=" + longitude);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Error getting geolocation:" + error);
        }
    );
} else {
    alert("Geolocation services are not supported by your web browser.");
}
```

I then go on to set some markers on a map using the Google Maps API.

Thank you very much,

Peter

**EDIT**

Here the code on JSFiddle showing the weird behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/JtmCV/

Comment: Please indent your code correctly! It would make it much easier for us to follow, as well as help you spot potential problems more easily!

Comment: Sorry about that. Should be better now (it was only the function name that was messed up).

Comment: Often if something works after an `alert()` in JS, I find it signifies a race condition somewhere. Are you sure the function's being skipped? Did you "step into" rather than "step over"?

Comment: Yes, I stepped into. I'm using Developer Tools in Chrome to debug if it's relevant.

Comment: Strange, the only thing I can think is that something is being returned asynchronously at some point after the callback is executed... How about if you wrap a `setTimeout()` around the body of the success callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your jsfiddle and it worked fine (Chrome 19 on Win 7), so I can't see why it should be causing problems.

Having said that, I'd strongly recommend switching to use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` instead of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. I recently did some work on a geolocation system and found `getCurrentPosition` can return unreliable cached positions, even if you use the options parameter to specify a low `maximumAge` value.

My latest version stops the watch after one of the following is true:

- the fifth position has been returned
- the accuracy is under 100m
- the time since the watch began is over 30 seconds